# Access subscriber variable

Tags: opentok, tokbox

```
var subscriber;
subscriber = void 0;

getApiAndToken = function() {
  initializeSession();
};

initializeSession = function() {
  session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
  session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
    session.subscribe(event.stream, 'layout', {
      insertMode: 'append'
    });
    layout();
  });
};

(function() {
  var movingAvg;
  subscriber.setStyle('audioLevelDisplayMode', 'off');
  movingAvg = null;
  return subscriber.on('audioLevelUpdated', function(event) {
    var logLevel;
    if (movingAvg === null || movingAvg <= event.audioLevel) {
      movingAvg = event.audioLevel;
    } else {
      movingAvg = 0.7 * movingAvg + 0.3 * event.audioLevel;
    }
    logLevel = Math.log(movingAvg) / Math.LN10 / 1.5 + 1;
    logLevel = Math.min(Math.max(logLevel, 0), 1);
    document.getElementById('subscriberMeter').value = logLevel;
    console.log(logLevel);
  });
});
```

Hey I'm having the issue where my session.subscribe is not connected to a subscriber variable, which I can tell is preferred as you want to accomplish more advanced settings with opentok.

Now I've essentially added the session on stream created into a function. Now what I'd like to be able to do is make session subscribe be related to the subscriber variable, to a point where I can also get the audio levels from it in my current code.

Currently I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStyle' of undefined
```

which is expected as I have it set as undefined on the top.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `session.subscribe()` is a Subscriber object. So all you need to do is modify the line which you call this method to store the return value:

```
subscriber = session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
  session.subscribe(event.stream, 'layout', {
    insertMode: 'append'
  });
  layout();
});
```

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: subscriber.setStyle is not a function